# I need to write an asynchronous function in JavaScript that sleeps for (millis) milliseconds and can resolve any value, but am unsure about await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout, asynchronous-javascript

I received this as a coding challenge, but am unfamiliar with the concepts of promises, awaits, and awaits.

```
// Asynchronous function that sleeps for a number of milliseconds
async function sleep(millis) {

    // Set timeout to new promise that resolves or rejects
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Call resolve
            resolve(millis);

        // Pass in milliseconds
        }), millis);

    });
        
};

/** 
 * let t = Date.now()
 * sleep(100).then(() => console.log(Date.now() - t)) // 100
 */
```

I'm unsure of what goes into calling back the resolve() function within the setTimeout(), what to pass in at the end of setTimeout(), and such.

Comment: This won't work because you don't resolve the actual outer Promise. Just remove the inner one and resolve in the regular, synchronous setTimeout function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: What exactly was the challenge? To fix the bug?

Comment: Here's the instructions: "Given a positive integer millis, write an asynchronous function that sleeps for millis milliseconds. It can resolve any value." It doesn't involve fixing any bugs, it involves writing code from scratch. I've looked at MDN about promises and such, but can't really find a workable solution.

Comment: The answer to your instruction is `setTimeout(resolveFunction, millis)` - the key is `asynchronous`.  If it's async, it doesn't "sleep" it *waits*.  Sleep = blocking, Wait=non-blocking, async=non-blocking.  The confusing part is *resolve any value* which doesn't mean anything in itself but *implies* the use of promise/resolve.

Comment: If it's an assignment (eg on a course) then you might like to get clarification first as you've not really "*written an asynchronous function*" (unless you simply wrap the `setTimout` in a function, which seems somewhat pointless).  But maybe the assignment is simply to find out about `setTimeout`?